# Can't use password in Kali Linux after changing username

Tags: passwords, kali-linux

I decided to change the username of my kali linux to a new one so I did the following commands :

changed both old_username (kali) to new_username (xyz) :

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

but when I did this one, I got "Sorry, try again." and finally "sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts"

```
sudo mv /home/kali/ /home/celsius/
```

Then I tried to go back to revert to old_username but I was locked out for writing on the file...

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

That's when I figured out that I change the username but not the name of the home folder meaning it doesn't know where to look for my settings... Tried to login as root but don't know how either

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: Just for curiosity... how come you didn't simply create a new user for yourself instead? The question as presented suggests that [Kali might not be for you](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). It's not a desktop distro, it's a security toolbox - and it's not the slightest newbie-friendly. If you're a Linux beginner you definitely should install a desktop distro for desktop use, and study Kali using a [pre-built virtual machine](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am in Kali Linux here.

The username you started with was root.

Most Linux is like this in that "root" is hidden.

It is not a good idea to change these, and generally no need.

Try:  [Kali Passwords](https://www.educba.com/kali-linux-default-passwords/)

```
We know Kali Linux has changed all the user policies after the version of 2020.1, due to this reason Kali Linux has two different default credentials which depend on the version as follows:

For version 2020.1 before:
Username : root
Password: toor
For version 2020.1 after:
Username : kali
Password: kali
```

If that does not work, you will have to reinstall Kali.

A virtual machine is a good idea for Kali (my VM app allows USB pass through for my Panda Wireless) so that is a good idea. I can make back ups for the VM if I have issues.